# Count the number of occurrences of a value in a column in r as you move down the column

Tags: r

I'd like to add a column to a dataframe that counts the number of occurrences in a different column as you move down each row.  For example if Name was the column I wanted to count occurrences of:

```
 Row    Name
 1      Tom
 2      Dave
 3      Tom
 4      Brent
 5      Brent
 6      Tom
```

I'd like the third column to read:

```
 Row    Name    Count
 1      Tom      1
 2      Dave     1
 3      Tom      2
 4      Brent    1
 5      Brent    2
 6      Tom      3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)

df = data.frame(Name=c('Tom','Dave','Tom','Brent','Brent','Tom'))
df %>% group_by(Name) 
  %>% mutate(Count=1:length(Name)) 
  %>% ungroup()
```

produces

```
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  Name  Count
  <chr> <int>
1 Tom       1
2 Dave      1
3 Tom       2
4 Brent     1
5 Brent     2
6 Tom       3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

data |> 
  group_by(Name) |> 
  mutate(Count = n())
```

The above should work

Comment: That didn't work as intended.  What that gave me was a total count of all names in each row.  For example, the first instance of Tom should have a 1 beside it, the next instance should have a 2 etc.  This solution gave the total count of Toms in each row.